# What's with [blank-page]s?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Is the [blank-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blank-page) tag useful?  There are currently 272 questions with the tag.

[image]

It seems mainly dominated by questions about blank output and issues with code. I'm not sure how the tag is supposed to be used.

**For reference**

[image]

I've no doubt people are going to ask about blank pages, and that many questions do indeed involve these blank pages, but do we really need such a tag? And if yes, what kind of blank page questions should be tagged with it?

Comment: 23618 hits [searching for questions containing 'blank page'](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+blank+page), 172 hits [searching for the tag blank-page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blank-page). That's 0,7% of askers familiar with the tag

Comment: I would say burn it.  "blank page" seems to be only something to be described in the body of the post.  I don't think we need to categorize "blank page" issues, which probably includes a plethora of causes.

Comment: @Jason, e.g. by inserting a few hundred spaces :)

Comment: @Huey I finished the job.

Comment: Thanks! We all appreciate your sacrifice.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

## OFFICIALLY BURNINATED AS OF [2015-06-04T08:55:58Z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913329/wordpress-missing-redirect-reponse-when-connected-to-network-or-vpn)

---

There's some [blank space](https://youtu.be/e-ORhEE9VVg) on the `long list of ex-lovers`—I mean ex-tags—for this one.

[image: Taylor Swift GIF of her singing "Got a long list of ex-lovers, they'll tell you I'm insane"]

Comment: This answer is terrifying. Take my upvote.

Comment: While he's taking care of this tag, can we also have Trogdor burninate that song?